# extract elements from php array and assign as variables

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, loops

I have been working on this for a while and cannot seem to figure it out at all. Any help would be appreciated. here we go.

I have an html form that has a text box and a submit button. the text entered in the text box is posted to my .php processor form. Once it gets here, I use:

```
$textdata = $_POST['textdata'];

$input = explode("\n", $textdata);
```

this takes the data, splits it by line, and stores each line in an array called `$input`.
from here i can echo `$input[0]` to get the first line and so on. But I need to use this further down in my script and need to assign a variable to the first line, or `$input[0]`.
`$input[0] = $line1;` does not work. I think I might have to use `extract()` and a foreach loop? Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: What you're describing should work. Can you try `var_dump()`'ing the `$input` array before and after modifying the first element to make sure?

Comment: Have you verified $input is in fact an array? Depending on server settings/encoding, the newline character may not be present, so your explode wouldn't work as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well fo one thing `$input` array will always be available, or what you can do if i understand correctly is:

```
$textdata = $_POST['textdata'];

$input = explode("\n", $textdata); //this should have the array of lines assuming
                                   //that $textdata was \n delimited

$line1 = $input[0]; //use $line1 later in code
```

Comment: wow, I was defining my variable backwards. that worked perfectly thank you so much.

Comment: You may want to tick this answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$line1 = $input[0];
$line2 = $input[1];
$line3 = $input[2];
// etc.
```

or:

```
for ($i=0, $inputlen = count($input); $i < $inputlen; $i++) {
    ${'line'.($i+1)} = $input[$i];
}
```

or simply:

```
list($line1, $line2, $line3) = $input;
```

Answer (score 0):

> $input[0]. $input[0] = $line1;

I can't tell if the full-stop in that line is a full-stop or concatenation operator.

For concatenation, it should be this way.

```
$input[0] = $input[0] . $line1;
```

or even shorter

```
$input[0] .= $line1;
```

---

If you're just wanting to assign `$input[0]` to `$line1` by value, it's

```
$line1 = $input[0];
```

You can also assign a reference using

```
$line1 =& $input[0];
```

Using the latter, any changes to `$line1` will be present in `$input[0]`.